# Hyperledger fabric Cli container errors

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, hyperledger-fabric

Currently working on custom deployments of hyperledger. I have the following docker compose file. Although when I try to access the cli with:

```
sudo docker exec -it cli bash
```

I get the error that it is not running:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 3a14a51f541c3dcce66b68155969eba87eb0ef6f9c869bffbc9a5c9d6867b13e is not running
```

Has anyone else encountered this error or have any idea why the container isn't running? It just seems strange as to why it isn't working.

```
version: '2'

networks:
  twoOrgsOneNode:

services:
  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA1_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - twoOrgsOneNode

  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA2_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2
    networks:
      - twoOrgsOneNode

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - twoOrgsOneNode

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - twoOrgsOneNode

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - twoOrgsOneNode

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME} ${DELAY}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - twoOrgsOneNode
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at the cli container logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the CLI container will exit after the scripts/script.sh has exited and TIMEOUT has expired. There was a change recently that someone added to reduce the default timeout to 10s, so it is possible that you have simply had the cli container exit normally.

If you want, you can comment out the `command: /bin/bash -c ...` line and then the container should just start up and wait for you exec into it.

e.g.

```
 cli:
    container_name: cli
...
   working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
   # command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME} ${DELAY}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
...
```

Comment: Thanks heaps I ended up working this exact solution out and it worked for me.

Comment: you are welcome... please mark as answered, if you don't mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

comment out this line in the docker-compose file:

```
command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
```

just like:

```
# command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
```